# 10-30v to 3.3v Level Shifting

Tags: level-shifting

Could someone point me towards a level shifter IC or circuit that can handle 10-30v to 3.3v shifting? It doesn't need to be fast or bidirectional just want to data log the state of some 12v and 24v switches. Trying to build a data-logging device with a 3.3v ESP32 micro-controller.

I've been scouring Google for a level shifter that can handle a voltage range for input but I've not been able to find one yet.

Any help would be appreciated. I've been stuck on this for a few weeks.

Comment: You might just want to use a comparator. Power it from 30 V, but get one with an open-drain output and pull up to 3.3 V.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this will work:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f70FhF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The output is low if the input is high. You may not need R1 if you can enable a built-in pullup resistor in the MCU.

Comment: This is pretty much what I do, too, but I add a capacitor and a reverse-biased diode in parallel with R2. The diode protects the transistor from negative voltages, and the capacitor filters out glitches and ESD spikes.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to get too complicated but sometimes you need to consider protection from ESD, reverse voltage and installation errors.

If the high state is 10 to 30V and the low state is 0V from load with switch open, there may be inductive back EMF transients below ground that need to be considered.

Either a passive R divider or a zener clamp with series resistor with a filter cap can be used.  Possibly, you might want to use a white or blue LED at 3V using 5 to 10mA.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fA31Nw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: My device will be hooked into the same 12-24v power source as the switches. I'm using a Step-Down Voltage Regulator (D24V25F3) to power the ESP32 microcontroller. So everything is sharing the same power and ground. The switches don't have any load other than an indicator LEDs. I just need to read if they are open or closed with my microcontroller. However I can't modify the equipment so I'm stuck with the switches at 12-24v.

Comment: Then D2 is not needed and the above will work. I hope the switches are rated <2A and thus gold plated to avoid lack of wetting current.